# When defining a property in TypeScript using let or otherwise, what is the best practice or rule on defining its type?

Tags: typescript, variables, types, properties

I am relatively new to TypeScript.

What are the rules or best practices for defining a type when declaring a property using `let`?

I was not able to find any documentation specific to this use case, albeit such a simple question.

Within a method, if I define properties like so:

```
let mode = 2;
let level = 'pro';
```

What are the rules here for defining their types? Or should we not define types here at all?

When I looked [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) I only saw one mention that sort of comes close to definitively answering my question as simple as it is. Scroll down or search for the comment line `// This assignment is allowed though!` to see it.

### Update

So, it seems that this is appropriate, but there was no documentation outlining best practices.

```
let mode:number = 2;
let level:string = 'pro';
```

I am currently working on an Angular 6 application, whereas the Angular compiler does not throw any errors if I do define types for simple properties like these.

Comment: Not defining a type means TypeScript will use *Type Inference* to determine the type. Explicitly setting the type is not bad practice at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i thought that might be the case, but felt the need to get some kind of confirmation here from the community. And I found a mention in the TypeScript documentation online, so i have updated my post.